# vb.net alter a button based on another button click

Tags: vb.net, button

I have a form with 80 Buttons on the form. Buttons are named `Button0` to `Button79`. 
If a button is clicked I need to alter the properties of the following two buttons.

As an example if `Button27` is clicked I need to change the visible property of `Button28` and `Button29`. I can't use the tag properties as they are already being used for another purpose.

I have a `Button_Click` sub with the handles set for all of the buttons. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Controls.Find` method.

```
private void NextButtonsVisibility(Button btnStart, int nextCount = 2, bool visible = true)
{
    const string buttonNameKey = "Button";

    var name = btnStart.Name; //name must be "Button#"
    var btnIndexStr = name.Substring(buttonNameKey.Length);
    var btnIndex = int.Parse(btnIndexStr);
    for (int i = 1; i <= nextCount; i++)
    {
        var btnNext = Controls.Find(buttonNameKey + (btnIndex + i), true).OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (btnNext != null)
            btnNext.Visible = visible;
    }
}
```

PS: An exception will be thrown if button name does not match with the rule.

***EDIT*** Forgot VB.NET tag.

```
Private Sub NextButtonsVisibility(btnStart As Button, Optional nextCount As Integer = 2, Optional visible As Boolean = True)
    Const  buttonNameKey As String = "Button"

    Dim name = btnStart.Name 'name must be "Button#"
    Dim btnIndexStr = name.Substring(buttonNameKey.Length)
    Dim btnIndex = Integer.Parse(btnIndexStr)
    For i As Integer = 1 To nextCount
        Dim btnNext = Controls.Find(buttonNameKey & btnIndex + i, True).OfType(Of Button)().FirstOrDefault()
        If btnNext IsNot Nothing Then
            btnNext.Visible = visible
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You code worked great after I made one edit:
 Dim btnNext = Controls.Find(buttonNameKey & btnIndex + i, True).OfType(Of Button)().FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @Terabithia Please accept it as answer. I will change this line too.